# Copy Cell contents between different Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Scenario: Workbook2.xlsx, Workbook1.xlsx, and VBA editor are open.   Workbook1.xlsx and Workbook2.xlsx are VBA projects as well each with one active sheet object called Sheet1(Sheet1). 
On the click of CommandButton5 in Workbook2, I want to move cells A1 to D10 in Workbook1 into Workbook2's A1 to D10.
When I move my mouse over "Set Move = ..." in debug mode, it says Move = Nothing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
  Dim Move As Range
  Set Move = Workbooks(Workbook1).Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,10))
  Move.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Workbooks(Workbook2).Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,10)).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes around the names of the workbooks.
Also, in order to work with the workbook (select ranges and do copy and paste), you explicitly need to activate the workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
  Dim Book As Workbook

  ' Get Workbook 1 and activate it   
  Set Book = Workbooks("Workbook1")
  Book.Activate

  Dim Move As Range
  Set Move = Book.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 10))
  Move.Select
  Selection.Copy

  ' Get Workbook 2 and activate it   
  Set Book = Workbooks("Workbook2")
  Book.Activate

  Set Move = Book.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 10))
  Book.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 10)).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

---

Also note that in order to work with multiple workbooks, they must all be opened in the same Excel instance (i.e. run in the same Excel process). If you have several workbooks opened in different Excel processes, you cannot access them all from the same macro.

---

Here is a variant that does not need to use the clipboard:

```
Sub CommandButton5_Click()

  Dim Source As Range
  Workbooks("Workbook1").Activate
  Set Source = Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 10))

  Dim Target As Range
  Workbooks("Workbook2").Activate
  Set Target = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 10))

  Target.Value = Source.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx. It says Run time error 1004. Select method of range class failed and points to "Move.select"

Comment: You're right in saying that all workbooks must be open in the same instance of excel,  but an instance of Excel 2013/2016 doesn't require that its workbooks share the same window, even if they are all under the same instance of Excel.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Thanks for the hint. I have corrected my text. I have only worked with Office up to 2010 so far.